# How To fix the cross-site forgery validation failed error in facebook sdk in php

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am New to the Facebook login with php.I am trying to Implement from Last week But I am not able to fix this issue.I have googled tried various ways but not fix my issue.Below is my code.Please somebody help me thanks in Advance.[this is error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39p3j.png)

```
 When I refersh it getting this error  SDK Exception :Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.
```

### This is login file

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';

$redirectUrl= "http://localhost/FacebookLogin/fbcallback.php";
$permissions= ['email'];
$LoginUrl   = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl,$permissions);
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input onclick="window.location='<?php echo $LoginUrl; ?>'"type="button" value="Login with Facebook"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### This is my config file

```
<?php

require_once "Facebook/autoload.php";
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook(['app_id'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'app_secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version'=>'v2.12'
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
```

### This is my callback file

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';

try{
  $accessToken=$helper->getAccessToken();
}catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e){
  echo "Response Exception :". $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e){
  echo "SDK Exception :". $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}
if(!$accessToken){
  //echo  "access token is".$accessToken;
  //die;
  header("location:login.php");
  exit();
}

$oAuth2Client=$fb->getOAuth2Client();
if(!$accessToken->isLongLived())
  $accessToken=$oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
$response =$fb->get("/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,picture.type(large),$accessToken");
$userData=$response->getGraphNode()-> asarray();
var_dump($userData);
$_SESSION['userdata']=$userData;
$_SESSION['access_Token']=string($accessToken);
header("location:index.php");
exit();
```